# handshake_failure for 2-way SSL enabled endpoint

Tags: java, spring, ssl

I have been trying to connect to a service endpoint which is 2 way SSL enabled. I am using Spring resttemplate.  I have added the certificate in keystore, but I am getting the below mentioned error:

```
>org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "path":Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
I enabled the SSL debus logs and in the logs I can see the warning as well:
<BEA-000000> <Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication>
```

Same code is working fine with same implementation on my DEV server, but not working on UAT server, but on UAT server REST call on same endpoint is working fine(which is also 2 way SSL enabled). Below is the code that I am using for SOAP and REST call:
REST:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ServReqRespLogMgr reqRespLogMgr = (ServReqRespLogMgr)UtilityMgr.getBean("servReqRespLogMgr");
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(PropertyUtil.getProperty("SSL_CONTEXT")));
        PasswordEncryptor pe = new PasswordEncryptor();
KeyManagerFactory factory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(PropertyUtil.getProperty("JKS_LOC_VALUE")), pe.decrypt(PropertyUtil.getProperty(IConstants.JKS_PWD_VALUE)).toCharArray());

factory.init(keyStore, pe.decrypt(PropertyUtil.getProperty(IConstants.JKS_PWD_VALUE)).toCharArray());

sc.init(factory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sc).build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
```

SOAP:

```
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) services;
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, filenetWsUrl);
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
headers.put("X-APPCERT", Arrays.asList(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(PropertyUtil.getProperty("FILENET_APP_CERT"))));
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,headers);
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, filenetWsUrl); 
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(PropertyUtil.getProperty("SSL_CONTEXT")));

KeyManagerFactory factory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(PropertyUtil.getProperty("JKS_LOC_VALUE")), jksPwd);

factory.init(keyStore, jksPwd);


sc.init(factory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

//sc.init(factory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
//End Trust Store

((BindingProvider) services).getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sc.getSocketFactory());
```

I checked the permission on keystore file which looks good. If I switch to one way SSL endpoint then also its working fine. My Java run time is 1.8.0_144 and my app server is WebLogic 12.2.1.3.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: The best info about an alert from the server is from the server. If you can't get that, _and_ since this apparently only occurs with 'two-way' (client auth), _and_ if you get a trace (with javax.net.debug=ssl or on the wire) and it shows the alert coming after client's second flight (Cert,CKX,CVer,CCS,Finished), then _probably_ it's your client's cert chain; look at that carefully, imagine the dozens of things a server _could_ dislike, and start going through them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you have to check.

1. Check if your Cert chain is properly created.
2. Add your certs to CACERTS file and configure weblogic to point to the CACERTS file.

This should most definitely resolve your problem.

Comment: This was the first thing that I tried but no luck. Also, in case there is any issue with CACERTS, even REST call should not work. I am making REST call on same web service endpoint with same authentication except for the REST cal I am using HTTP GET.

Comment: @Sumit you are not using TLSv1 right? if you do, There is no support for that after Java 7. You might have to upgrade to latest TLS versions

Comment: I am using TLSv1.2 and Java version is 1.8.0_144